# Query execution problem using Spring and HIbernate together with FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, spring, orm, persistence

So I'm going to be using Flex 4 with Spring and Hibernate.
Everything is configured and working. I know this as I can do simple queries, like listing all values in a table.
Problem is when I try to perform a 'select' query, then I get all the values, as I was getting before, and not the specific attributes through Select query.

I'm a beginner, so kindly overlook my lack of more technically sound words..but I don use them as I don wanna mis-quote.

Following is some code which will make You understand things better:
This is class used to store data coming from the MySQL database--

```
package flex;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="intrial1")
public class intrial1 implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column( name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column( name = "name")
    private String name;



    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    }
```

This is the class where the sessionFactory does things(too many import statements, just to try to make things work-ignore)--

```
package flex;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQueries;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingDestination;
import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingInclude;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;



import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;




@Repository
@RemotingDestination
public class SpringBean_Service  {


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        sessionFactory = factory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RemotingInclude
    @Transactional
    public List<intrial1> getList() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from intrial1 ").list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RemotingInclude
    @Transactional
    public List<intrial1> getListAgain() {



        org.hibernate.Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select id from intrial1 where name='chirayu'");
        List l = q.list();
        return l; 


    }


    @RemotingInclude
    @Transactional
    public void createFriend(String name, int id) {
        intrial1 f = new intrial1();
        f.setName(name);
        f.setId(id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(f);

}
}
```

> In above class, getList() works
>   perfect, lists all the values. The
>   createFriend is used to enter values
>   of id+name, and works smoothly. The
>   problem is with getListAgain()
>   function, it gives me a result,
>   imagine 2 columns, having heading as
>   'id' and 'name', but listing id values
>   in both the columns (No names), As You
>   can understand, I am looking for
>   result of getListAgain() function as -
>   "1 column having header as 'id', and
>   listing id wherever the name
>   ='chirayu'".

Kindly help, as I will need to clear this and move ahead with development.
Thank You.

Regards,
Chirayu

***UPDATE NOTE:*** Would like to say one thing here, if only I make a class as below, which is identical to **intrial1 class**, but has no return statement for name, i.e., **no getName() defined**, I get my correct result for the query -

> 'select id from intrial1 where
>   name='chirayu''

```
package flex;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity

public class intrial2 {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column( name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column( name = "name")
    private String name;




    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    }
```

Is this strange or meant to be like this. Still looking for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query

```
select id from intrial1 where name='chirayu'
```

doesn't return intrial1 entity, so you should change return type to List or simply change your query to:

```
from intrial1 where name='chirayu'
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Maurizio, but changing the return type to 'List', makes it not possible to connect using Blazeds, because it has no Data Provider(which was the point of having intrial1 class).
Also, Changing the query as You advised only gives back 2 columns-1st 'id', 2nd 'name', with the restriction of only listing values matching name='chirayu'.

I tried both things and then a replying, so am pretty sure...Kindly help further if You or anybody else can.

Comment: Does change anything if method getListAgain return a List<Integer>?

Comment: Otherwise you could create a new Object called f.i. intrlialDTO with only id and try to get from hibernate in this way: 
select new intrlialDTO(id)
from intrlial where name='chrayu'

Comment: Thanks again for replying Maurizio, Well 'List<Integer>', has thre same problem as using only 'List', i.e., NO DATASTORE(no intrial1 kind of entity).
As for your 2nd suggestion, Is it not same as what I have updated above, kindly see..I created a new class intrial2, which returned only id...see and help further.
Wish others would contribute too...I get a feeling, I'm missing out on something essential.